# Statistics test for concentration of extract effecting germination

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation, statistical-significance

I am undertaking biology course work and am a little stuck.

My experimental hypothesis is: There is a significant correlation between increasing tomato extract concentrations and reduced seed germination.

Which statistical test would be best?

Answer (score 1):

Pearson's correlation is usually what is intended when the word "correlation" is used without qualification.

That said, a good starting point is to look at a scatterplot of your two variables. There are plenty of options for how best to assess the negative relationship implied by your question. Depending on distributions you might want to transform your variables; or you might be interested in some other index of association such as Spearman's rho or Kendall's tau or ordinal optimal scaling or polychoric correlation and so on.